# How do you handle time-series that span weekends and non-work hours

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search

I am working on a class that is going to contain objects with a time stamp and multiple measurements. These measurements are usually taken from 08:00 and until 16:00 every weekday, but needs to be flexible. Now, what I want is to be able to do is specify a time-interval, let's say 1 hour, and get the average. Something like myArrayList.getAvrageHeight(), and have this return the the average height from all the measurements of the last hour. I plan on keeping only the needed entries in my list, and remove those that are "timed out".

Doing this within the same day is quite straight-forward. But I would like, that when I call this method at 08.15 on Tuesday morning, myArrayList will contain 45minutes worth of data from Monday, and 15 Minutes worth of data from Tuesday.

One of my biggest constrains is that the measurements come in at arbitrary intervals, anything from 1 minute, and down to multiple times per second.

So far I got this for computing the averages every time a measurement is added:

```
protected void computeAvrages() {

    averageWeight = 0;
    averageSpeed = 0;
    averageHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < super.size(); i++) {
        averageWeight += super.get(i).getWeight();
        averageSpeed += super.get(i).getSpeed();
        averageHeight += super.get(i).getHeight();
    }

    averageWeight = averageWeight/super.size();
    averageSpeed = averageSpeed/super.size();
    averageHeight = averageHeight/super.size();

}
```

My objects, look like this:

```
public class Car {

    double weight;
    double speed;
    double height;

    int timeStamp;

    public Car(int timeStamp, double weight, double speed, double height) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.height = height;
    }


    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public double getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }
}
```

myArrayList is sorted on timeStamp in ascending order (I can use binary search on this list), and the amount of records I am planning on keeping will be from 1.000 -> 500.000 depending on traffic (about 3 cars per second for a week) The time-interval is kept as seconds, so when I specify 1 hour, I store it as 3600.

When I call myArrayList.add(aCar), computeAvrages get called, but what I wonder is the following:

1. How should I handle the change of Monday -> Tuesday, and from Friday to Monday?
2. I am currently storing start and stop times as startHour, startMinute, stopHour and stopMinute for simplicity, how would you have stored these time-references?

This problem might be to complex for stackoverflows question->answer type, but I'll try and make it simpler:

You are looking at a highway. Cars are passing by. Every car that passes by gets recorded with Weight, Height and Speed. Now, I want to be able to specify a time of day (i.e. 08:00 until 16:00) that interests me. Only cars that pass by during the work week is interesting (aka Monday -> Friday) I would only store cars passing by in this period, but I still get notified about cars that pass by outside of this timeframe.

I then want to compute a 1 Hour average of cars passing by within my timeframe. But at 08:15 on Tuesday I am not interested in only getting the average of the last 15 minutes, but I want the average of the last 45 minutes on Monday combined with the first 15 of Tuesday. So my questions above apply.

Comment: Thanks a lot for every answer. I need to look over my data-model and see if I can't narrow down my question(s) a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is so complex that I (and many others) have more questions rather than answers. Anyways here is my two cents looking at the last two paragraphs of your question.

I would use the following classes:

1. class `CarEvent` with three properties - `wight, height, speed`
2. class `EventTimeStamp` with two properties - `Date, ts`. ts is of type short with range 0800 to 1600. The class should have two methods - `subtract(int days, int hours)` and `add(int days,int hours)` both returning another instance of EventTimeStamp.
3. class `TrafficLog` that holds all the CarEvents in a `LinkedListMap`. A LinkedListMap is Map that allows sequential access too so that you can do binary search. The key to the map should be an instance of EventTimeStamp

With this data-structure, you can implement the analytical methods that you desire on the TrafficLog class. For example, to get the average:

```
public float getAverageTraffic(EventTimeStamp startDate, int durationHours)
{
    EventTimeStamp startEventTS = startDate.subtract(0,durationHours);
    CarEvent startEvent = eventList.get(startEventTS); //there might not be an event at exactly this point. So some tolerance have to be built in to this.
    CarEvent endEvent = eventList.get(startDate);
    return getAverage(startEvent,endEvent);//the two params are part of a linked list, so you can iterate and compute the average.
}
```

Comment: Yes, my question was to complex.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the total number of entries (in the time period) by the total time period.

Using your example:  If it is 8:15 on Tuesday morning. And you want the last 15 minutes plus the last 45 minutes from the day before to complete an average for that hour.  (Which is really strange by the way), then take the data from the last 45 minutes of the day before and sum it with the last 15 minutes for your average.

As far as data structures are concerned, then your "real-time" average, would hold an hour of values.  As a minute within your time-period passed you would be adding data on one side and removing from the other side.  This would allow you to have an hour that might span between two days.

Comment: Well, that is the easy part, actually finding the average. What I want to know is how to handle the day and weekend transitions, as well as any point regarding the removal of items (but that is secondary).

Comment: I don't understand your question then.  What do you mean by "handle the transitions"?  You don't need to handle them if you have your start and stop times.

Comment: I have a start and stop time for every day. So any cars passing by earlier than 08:00 or later than 16:00 will just be discarded as you try to add them. So now at 09:00, I will have 1 hour worth of data, and anything in my arraylist older than currentTime+time-window is getting removed every time I add a new car. But what does then happen at 16:15? If I continue to use this method, I will only have 45 minutes worth of data, as I will discard anything older than currentTime+TimeWindow, but I'll not get any new data. If I then pull for an average at 17:00, my arrayList will be empty.

Comment: @karl your example is missing something.  It doesn't make sense, I don't understand why you are looking at cars after 16:00?  What 45 minutes worth of data are you refering to?  CurrentTime + time window is a future time, right?  Please update your question with a complete example.

Comment: Added a section under my questions to give a description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly... From 15:15 to 16:15 you get the average: 2.  From 8:15 to 9:15 you get the average: 3.

You want to take the time from 16:00 to 16:15 and include it in the average time from 8:15 to 9:00.

Is this a programming problem or a math problem?  Because if it's a math problem, it seems you should take (15/60) * 2 + (45/60) * 3 to get your morning average (from 8:00 to 9:00).

But, you'd want to do this every hour, not just the hours separating days.  If your sample was from 8:30 to 9:30 and from 9:30 to 10:30, you should probably average every sample together.

Comment: _You want to take the time from 16:00 to 16:15 and include it in the average time from 8:15 to 9:00._

Comment: _You want to take the time from 16:00 to 16:15 and include it in the average time from 8:15 to 9:00._ Yes this is kind of what I want, but when I only keep useful measurements in my list, I can just take an average of all items in the list, and it is a programming problem, how should I handle my array list, when trying to keep only the appropriate measurements in the list? How should I know how far back in time my oldest measurement will be? Because on Tuesday @ 08:15, it will be at Monday 15:15(many hours in the past), but on Tuesday 09:00 it will just be my timeFrame in the past.

Comment: That sounds like a data structure problem.  Why not in the class that holds an hour's period of time you have a variable called "Valid".  Valid, when 0/false, means that you should skip it.  Valid, when 1/true, means that you shouldn't skip it.

Comment: Karl, shouldn't you take the time from 5:15 to 6:00 as an incomplete average of that hour?  Taking the first 15 minutes of a completely non-consecutive hour is very bad math/statistics.

Also, could you give an example of the data set you have to work with?  Like, give an example hour, an hour with no/invalid data, and a data set that covers the weekend.

Comment: Also, could you specifically label/point to a piece of code or line of code that you are having trouble with?